# C++ struct two dimension array into C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, marshalling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination.” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671658/what-does-invalid-managed-unmanaged-type-combination-mean)

how we will code these structures(Written in C++) in C#

```
typedef struct tagBIRDMATRIX
{
short   n[3][3];    // array of matrix elements
}BIRDMATRIX;
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  If so, please give us that information.  Otherwise, look up docs on .Net pInvoke.

Comment: Merlyn Morgan-Graham you r right, it is got some similarity.Let me edit my question.sorry about that...

Answer (score 7):

The size should be the number of elements in your cross product.

```
 struct BIRDMATRIX
 {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 9)]
    short[,] n;
 }
```

Comment: Neat trick, I was trying to use `fixed` with good 'ol multidimensional arrays but that doesn't compile. You can however do stuff like this `fixed short n[3 * 3]` but yours truly is better.

Comment: it is got error,"Error 1 Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type."

Comment: @John, yea try and stay away from fixed and pointers in C# if you can help it. They are handy in a language that doesn't treat you like a two year old, but usually a pain in the ole arse when you need them in c#. I love .NET but sometimes, I just want my pointers back.

Comment: @LMC008 Sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: @LMC008 Check it now. I always mix that up.

Comment: @LMC008 , that should work. You don't need unsafe anymore though.